# (Edit) How do I solve this limit (using the limit definition)?

Tags: limits, derivatives, definition

If $f$ is differentiable in 1 and $f′(1)=2$, calculate $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(1+h)−f(1)}{\sqrt 
h}$$
What I did was equate this to $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h} \sqrt h$.

Since the first operand of the product is the definition of the first derivative, I substituted it for $f'(1)$ and ended up with $\lim_{h \to 0^+}f'(1)\sqrt h$.

Substituting further, I got $\lim_{h \to 0^+}2\sqrt h$.

Know this seems correct to me so far, but it seemed too easy for an exam question and I am wondering if I missed something.

Comment: You shouldn't (in general) post a question like this without any attempt of your own. It seems like you've just copied and pasted your homework - it's not that people aren't willing to help you understand your homework, it's that **they aren't willing to just do it for you**. Please edit the question to add your own solution attempt

Comment: I tried it on my own several times and I ended up with Gio's solution. I was just trying to see if I went wrong somewhere or if I missed something. So the answer should be zero?

Comment: That's absolutely fine, I understand. Just make sure in future to try and add context (i.e. by adding your solution attempt) - it means that others can help you out better (since they know exactly which step confused you) and it also gives a better impression. But yes - the correct answer indeed should be $0$, and the solution @Gio gave (which is what you arrived at as well) is a completely valid solution. You've come up with an equivalent expression, and by using the limit of the product is the product of the limits (when both limits exist) - the answer is indeed $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{\sqrt{h}}=\sqrt{h}\times \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$.